# Randomizing without duplicating

Tags: python, random

I am trying to make a riddle game in python but the problem is random function is repeating questions. I want that questions do not repeat can someone please help

Comment: please share the code section where you are randomising!

Comment: Put the questions in a list. Shuffle the list. Process the shuffled list in order.

Comment: @Barmar, it still _can_ repeat the questions!

Comment: @anurag Only if there are duplicates in the original list or you go back to the beginning for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Place all the questions in the list and use this function

```
import random
random_indexes=random.sample(range(len(lst), no_of_questions))
```

Then iterate over the random_indexes and get the questions.